# Reading writing fortran direct access unformatted files with different compilers

Tags: fortran, binaryfiles, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have a section in a program that writes a direct-access binary file as follows:

```
open (53, file=filename, form='unformatted', status='unknown',
& access='direct',action='write',recl=320*385*8)
write (53,rec=1) ulat
write (53,rec=2) ulng
close(53)
```

This program is compiled with ifort. However, I cannot reconstruct the data correctly if I read the data file from a different program compiled with gfortran. If the program reading the data is also compiled in ifort, then I can correctly reconstruct the data. Here's the code reading the data file:

```
OPEN(53, FILE=fname, form="unformatted", status="unknown", access="direct", action="read", recl=320*385*8)
READ(53,REC=2) DAT
```

I do not understand why this is happening? I can read the first record correctly with both compilers, it's the second record that I cannot reconstruct properly if I mix the compilers.

Comment: Can you write it out in text format? So you can see it?

Or does it have to be in binary format?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ifort and gfortran do not use the same block size for record length by default.  In ifort, the value of `recl` in your `open` statement is in 4-byte blocks, so your record length isn't 985,600 bytes, it is 3,942,400 bytes long.  That means the records are written at intervals of 3.9 million bytes.

gfortran uses a `recl` block size of 1 byte and your record length is 985,600 byes.  When you read the first record, everything works, but when you read the second record you look at 985,600 bytes into the file but the data is at 3,942,400 bytes into the file.  This also means you are wasting a ton of data in the file, as you are using only 1/4 of its size.

There are a couple ways to fix this:

- In ifort specify recl in 4-byte blocks, e.g. `320*385*2` instead of `*8`
- In ifort, use the compile flag `-assume byterecl` to have `recl` values interpreted as bytes.
- In gfortran compensate for the size and use `recl=320*385*32` so that your reads are correctly positioned.

A better way, however, is to engineer agnosticism in the `recl` unit size. You can use `inquire` to figure out the recl of an array.  For example:

```
real(kind=wp), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: recltest
integer :: reclen
allocate(recltest(320,385))
inquire(iolength=reclen) recltest
deallocate(recltest)
...
open (53, file=filename, form='unformatted', status='unknown',
& access='direct',action='write',recl=reclen)
...
OPEN(53, FILE=fname, form="unformatted", status="unknown", &
access="direct", action="read", recl=reclen)
```

This will set `reclen` to the value needed to store a `320x385` array based on the that compilers base unit for record length.  If you use this when both writing and reading your code will work with both compilers without having to use compile-time flags in `ifort` or compensate with hardcoded recl differences between compilers.

---

## An illustrative example

### Testcase 1

```
program test
  use iso_fortran_env
  implicit none

  integer(kind=int64), dimension(5) :: array
  integer :: io_output, reclen, i
  reclen = 5*8 ! 5 elements of 8 byte integers.

  open(newunit=io_output, file='output', form='unformatted', status='new', &
       access='direct', action='write', recl=reclen)

  array = [(i,i=1,5)]  
  write (io_output, rec=1) array
  array = [(i,i=101,105)]
  write (io_output, rec=2) array
  array = [(i,i=1001,1005)]
  write (io_output, rec=3) array

  close(io_output)
end program test
```

This program writes an array of 5 8-byte integers 3 times to the file in records 1,2 and 3.  The array is 5*8 bytes and I have hardcoded that number as the recl value.

#### Testcase 1 with gfortran 5.2

I compiled this testcase with the command line:

```
gfortran -o write-gfortran write.f90
```

This produces the output file (interpreted with `od -A d -t d8`):

```
0000000                    1                    2
0000016                    3                    4
0000032                    5                  101
0000048                  102                  103
0000064                  104                  105
0000080                 1001                 1002
0000096                 1003                 1004
0000112                 1005
0000120
```

The arrays of 5 8-bye elements are packed contiguously into the file and record number 2 (`101 ... 105`) starts where we would expect it to at offset 40, which is the recl value in the file `5*8`.

#### Testcase 1 with ifort 16

This is compiled similarly:

```
ifort -o write-ifort write.f90
```

And this, for the exact same code, produces the output file (interpreted with `od -A d -t d8`):

```
0000000                    1                    2
0000016                    3                    4
0000032                    5                    0
0000048                    0                    0
*
0000160                  101                  102
0000176                  103                  104
0000192                  105                    0
0000208                    0                    0
*
0000320                 1001                 1002
0000336                 1003                 1004
0000352                 1005                    0
0000368                    0                    0
*
0000480
```

The data is all there but the file is full of 0 valued elements.  The lines starting with `*` indicate every line between the offsets is 0.  Record number 2 starts at offset 160 instead of 40.  Notice that 160 is 40*4, where 40 is our specified recl of `5*8`.  By default ifort uses 4-byte blocks, so a recl of 40 means a physical record size of 160 bytes.

If code compiled with gfortran were to read this, records 2,3 and 4 would contain all 0 elements and a read of record 5 would correctly read the array written as record 2 by ifort.  An alternative to have gfortran read record 2 where it lies in the file would be to use `recl=160` (4*5*4) so that the physical record size matches what was written by ifort.

Another consequence of this is wasted space.  Over-specifying the recl means you are using 4 times the necessary disk space to store your records.

#### Testcase 1 with ifort 16 and `-assume byterecl`

This was compiled as:

```
ifort -assume byterecl -o write-ifort write.f90
```

And produces the output file:

```
0000000                    1                    2
0000016                    3                    4
0000032                    5                  101
0000048                  102                  103
0000064                  104                  105
0000080                 1001                 1002
0000096                 1003                 1004
0000112                 1005
0000120
```

This produces the file as expected.  The command line argument `-assume byterecl` tells ifort to interpret any `recl` values as bytes rather than double words (4-byte blocks).  This will produce writes and reads that match code compiled with gfortran.

### Testcase 2

```
program test
  use iso_fortran_env
  implicit none

  integer(kind=int64), dimension(5) :: array
  integer :: io_output, reclen, i
  inquire(iolength=reclen) array
  print *,'Using recl=',reclen

  open(newunit=io_output, file='output', form='unformatted', status='new', &
       access='direct', action='write', recl=reclen)

  array = [(i,i=1,5)]  
  write (io_output, rec=1) array
  array = [(i,i=101,105)]
  write (io_output, rec=2) array
  array = [(i,i=1001,1005)]
  write (io_output, rec=3) array

  close(io_output)
end program test
```

The only difference in this testcase is that I am inquiring the proper recl to represent my 40-byte array (5 8-byte integers).

#### The output

gfortran 5.2:

```
 Using recl=          40
```

ifort 16, no options:

```
 Using recl=          10
```

ifort 16, `-assume byterecl`:

```
 Using recl=          40
```

We see that for the 1-byte blocks used by gfortran and ifort with the `byterecl` assumption that recl is `40`, which equals our 40 byte array.  We also see that by default, ifort uses a recl of 10, which means 10 4-byte blocks or 10 double words, both of which mean 40 bytes.  All three of these testcases produce identical file output and read/writes from either compiler will function properly.

## Summary

To have record-based, unformatted, direct data be portable between ifort and gfortran the easiest option is to just add `-assume byterecl` to the flags used by ifort.  You really should have been doing this already since you are specifying record lengths in bytes, so this would be a straightforward change that probably has no consequences for you.

The other alternative is to not worry about the option and use the `inquire` intrinsic to query the `iolength` for your array.

Comment: That was a very helpful explanation. But i would request clarification on a few points though: (i) i don't understand "byte-units", i thought the record length would simply be the size_of_array*size_of_datatype. (ii) in your proposed first fix you say to use 320*385*2, but you say the recl is 4-byte units, so why not 320*385*4? (iii) if I use inquired recl length for reading (the code for writing is left the same) then reading doesn't work with both ifort and gfortran. Why did it stop working with ifort? Thanks casey!

Comment: @deepak (i) if you have an 8 byte data type and the recl is specific in 4-byte blocks, you only need 2 of those to store 8 bytes.  If the recl is specified in 1-byte blocks then you need 8 of them to store 8 bytes.  (ii) if recl is in 4-byte blocks and you multiply array_size*4 you are specifying 16 bytes per array element, which is too much unless you are writing quad-precision reals.  (iii) make sure you are using an array of the same type, kind, rank with the same dimensions that you will be writing or the inquired iolength will not be right for you arrays.

Comment: @deepak see the examples I added to the answer and see if they help.

Comment: really helpful answer! I appreciate your effort :)