# "End Of File" Error While Converting ASCII to GRD

Tags: unix, fortran, ascii, gfortran

I am trying to run a FORTRAN program (with `gfortran`) where I convert an ASCII file to a GRD file. I'm expecting the program to read a text file and then output a `grd` file.

After running the program, I am getting the following error message:

**Fortran runtime error: End of file**

Below are the files that I am working with:

**Terminal Commands:**

```
gfortran ascii2grd.f90
./a.out
```

**FORTRAN Program:**

```
!PROGRAM TO CONVERT ASCII TO GRD 
program ascii2grd
parameter(nx=25,ny=23,np=1)
real u(nx,ny,np),temp1(nx,ny)

open(2,file='/home/weather/test.grd',
form='unformatted',access='direct',recl=nx*ny*4)  
open(1,file='/home/weather/out.dat')

 do k=1,np
 read(1,*)((u(j,i,k),j=1,nx),i=1,ny)
10  continue    
 enddo

 rec=1
 do kk=1,np
 write(2,rec=irec)((u(j,i,kk),j=1,nx),i=1,ny)
 write(*,*)'Processing...'
irec=irec+1
 enddo
 write(*,*)'Done!'

stop
end
```

**Sample from out.dat**

```
   999.000000    
   11.1000004    
   999.000000    
   999.000000    
   16.7000008    
   999.000000    
   14.6000004    
   999.000000    
   999.000000    
   999.000000
```

Comment: Avoid using units 1,2 to 10, some of them are pre-connected for special purposes. It does not make a problem here, but it may bite you in the future.

Comment: Are you sure `nx` and `ny` is correct? Try to add an empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: I'm learning FORTRAN right now, how are `nx` and `ny` calculated?

Comment: You have them as `nx=25,ny=23` in your code. They must correspond to the number of values in the datafile.

Comment: Uh, and you **must** use `IMPLICIT NONE`! You have some undeclared variables there. The RECL value is also dubious, you should use `inquire` to be sure, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686720/reading-writing-fortran-direct-access-unformatted-files-with-different-compilers

Comment: how many values in out.dat? code expects 575 (nx\*ny\*np)

Comment: out.dat contains 572 values. Does that mean that `nx` and `ny` have to equal 572?

Comment: Ok I figured out the nx*ny*np issue... That line needed to be formatted as `parameter(nx=26,ny=22,np=1)`