# reading hexadecimal data from file in fortran

Tags: fortran, hex, gfortran

In Fortran, I'm trying to read a file with data in 8-bit (hexadecimal) bytes, on Linux.

In 'hexedit' the first line looks as it should, for the tiff-file it is.

```
49 49 2A 00  08 00 20 00  00 00 0B 02  00 00 00 00  II*... .........
```

I declare a two-byte character variable (`character(len=2)   :: tifhead(8)`)
and read like this:

```
      open(1,file=filename,access='stream')
      read(1) tifhead,greyvalue
```

I get the first two (`49 49`), which print out as II in a formatted write
(format (2Z2), but not the other ones.

How can I get all these hex values out? I should see `49 49 2A 00 08 .......`
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure if I had to massively modify my previous answers (since I believe they still serve a purpose), so I decided to just add yet another answer, hopefully the last one. I apologize for the verbosity.

The following Fortran 90 module provides a subroutine named `tiff_reader_16bit` which reads any TIFF data file and returns its 16-bit content in an array of integers:

```
module tiff_reader
implicit none
private
public :: tiff_reader_16bit
contains
subroutine tiff_reader_16bit(filename, tifdata, ndata)
character(len=*), intent(in) :: filename
integer, allocatable, intent(out) :: tifdata(:)
integer, intent(out) :: ndata
integer, parameter :: max_integers=10000000
integer :: unt, status, record_length, i, records, lsb, msb
character ch;
integer, dimension(max_integers) :: temp
ndata=0
inquire(iolength=record_length) ch
open(newunit=unt, file=filename, access='direct', form='unformatted',&
     action='read', status='old', iostat=status, recl=record_length)
if (status /= 0) then
  print "(3a)","Error reading file """,filename,""": File not found."; return
end if
records=1
do i=1,max_integers
  read(unit=unt, rec=records, iostat=status) ch; msb=ichar(ch)
  if (status /= 0) then; records=records-1; ndata=i-1; exit; end if
  read(unit=unt, rec=records+1, iostat=status) ch; lsb=ichar(ch)
  if (status /= 0) then; ndata=i; temp(ndata)=msb; exit; end if
  temp(i)=lsb+256*msb; records=records+2
end do
close(unit=unt)
if (ndata==0) then
  print "(a)","File partially read."; records=records-1; ndata=max_integers
end if
allocate(tifdata(ndata), stat=status); tifdata=temp(:ndata)
print "(2(i0,a),/)",records," records read, ",ndata," 16-bit integers returned."
end subroutine tiff_reader_16bit
end module tiff_reader
```

The subroutine gets the TIFF file name and returns an array of integers, together with the the total number of integers read. Internally, the subroutine uses a fixed-size array `temp` to temporarily store the data. To save memory, the subroutine returns an allocatable array `tifdata` which is part of `temp`, containing the data that was read only. The maximum number of data read is set in the parameter `max_integers` to 10 million, but can go up to `huge(0)` if necessary and if memory allows (in my system that's about 2.14 billion integers); it can go even further if you use "higher" `kind` of integers. Now, there are other ways to do that, avoiding the use of a temporary fixed-size array, but this usually comes at the cost of additional computation time, and I wouldn't go that way. More sophisticated implementations can also be done, but that would add more complexity to the code, and I don't think it fits here.

Since you need the results in the form of 16-bit data, two consecutive bytes from the file must be read, then you treat them as most significant byte first, less significant byte next. This is why the first byte read in each iteration is multiplied by 256. Note that this is NOT always the case in binary files (but it is in TIFF). Some binary files come with less significant byte first.

The subroutine is lengthier than the previous examples I posted, but that's because I added error checking, which is actually necessary. You should always check if the file exists and if end of file has been reached while reading it. Special care must also be taken for TIFF images with an "orphan" last byte (this is indeed the case for the sample file "FLAG_T24.TIF" which I found [here](https://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/sample/index.htm) - but not the case for the sample image "MARBLES.TIF" found at the same webpage).

An example driver program using the module above would be:

```
program tiff_reader_example
use tiff_reader
implicit none
integer :: n
integer, allocatable :: tifdata(:)
call tiff_reader_16bit("FLAG_T24.TIF", tifdata, n);
if (n > 0) then
  print "(a,7(z4.4,tr1),z4.4,a)", "First 8 integers read: (", tifdata(:8), ")"
  print "(a,7(z4.4,tr1),z4.4,a)", " Last 8 integers read: (", tifdata(n-7:), ")"
  deallocate(tifdata)
end if
end program tiff_reader_example
```

Running the program gives:

```
46371 records read, 23186 16-bit integers returned.

First 8 integers read: (4949 2A00 0800 0000 0E00 FE00 0400 0100)
 Last 8 integers read: (F800 F8F8 00F8 F800 F8F8 00F8 F800 00F8)
```

which is correct. Note that in this case the number of records (= bytes, since the file is opened as `unformatted`) is not double the number of integers returned. That's because this particular sample image has that "orphaned" last byte I mentioned earlier. Also note that I used another format to print 16-bit hexadecimals, including leading zeroes if needed.

There are more detailed explanations that can be given but this thread is already quite long. Feel free to ask in the comments if something is not clear.

**EDIT**: By default intel Fortran treats direct access records as 4-byte words, which doesn't seem quite right to me. This unusual behavior can be fixed with a compiler flag, but to avoid the lack of portability in case someone uses that specific compiler without such a flag, I slightly modified the module `tiff_reader` to take care of this.

Comment: Note that Fortran 2003 brought the stream access which is more directly suited to read streams of bytes or streams of binary variables possibly of various size.

Comment: @VladimirF: `access='stream'` won't help much in this case because there is no portable way to implement integers of _exactly_ 16-bit. This would be necessary to read each 16-bit integer directly (without the need to read it byte-by-byte and without reading more data than needed). However, `selected_int_kind`  works with powers of 10, not 2; perhaps borrowing `int16_t` type with `iso_c_binding` or some other trick would help, but I wouldn't do that to save 3 lines of code. `stream` access is very useful but not in this particular case. Using it would just omit `recl=1` in `open` statement.

Comment: Of course there is, you named it yourself. `integer(c_int16_t)` or `integer(int16)` where `int16` is defined in `iso_fortran_env`. That is not trick, that is using normal Fortran capabilities. Also, you are making a mistake assuming that recl is counted in bytes. That is NOT portable. Many Fortran compilers store direct access records in 4-byte words an your program will not work. Using direct access to read byte streams is a trick. And it does not always work. See, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686720/reading-writing-fortran-direct-access-unformatted-files-with-different-compilers

Comment: @VladimirF: I knew it can be done with `c_int16_t`, I named it before you did, and there is a reason I opted not to use it. The code I posted _is_ correct and works on any compiler I tried, plus it doesn't need `-std=f2003` (or whatever the flag is in a given compiler). F0003 is, sadly, not very well supported by several compilers, and while I use even F2008 features whenever it is appropriate, I still opted for a "conservative" answer here. Also note that the compiler will NOT store anything in this case, it just reads a TIFF file created by another program with a specific format.

Comment: OMG, I know that you named it and I did acknowledged it. No, your code is not portable and any real usage of direct access should include `inquire` to get the right `recl`. Gfortran does  not need any special compiler for Fortran 2003 nor does it need any other compiler I know. Also, it does not matter if store or read, the point is that several compilers (like Intel Fortran) use **4-byte words**. If you write `recl=1` you get **4 bytes**, NOT 1 byte. Do read the link carefully in my previous comment carefully. BTW, stream access is well supported even in the old g95.

Comment: @VladimirF I tried to minimize the length of the code without sacrificing at least some error proofing. `inquire` could/should be used but I wasn't posting an essay covering every possible approach - just an answer to a specific question, which I tried to to keep it simple AND effective. Feel free to post another answer with a more sophisticated solution which would be more helpful than commenting on how my "wrong" code won't work (?) on Intel Fortran, which, by the way, is a compiler I am not particularly interested after some previous experience using it, so I won't read the link carefully.

Comment: The link is about standard Fortran, not about Intel Fortran specifics, but never mind. I mentioned the salient points about portability here. We have had several questions where people had problems because they did stuff like `recl=1` or `recl=4`.

Comment: @VladimirF Again, feel free to post a "better" answer covering every possible compiler in F20003 or F2008 and/or using techniques I am perfectly aware of and opted not to use in this particular case. In the meantime, I do hope my answer will help the person asked.

Comment: Thank you guys for this discussion, which I must admit is partly over my head. I solved the problem another way. I read in the data as an array of integer(kind=2). This gives me  15-bit signed integers. Those from 0 to 32767 (2^15-1) are as intended: those larger come out as negative numbers (because, apparently, on my system with a little-endian convention the heaviest bit is the sign bit) that start at -32767. If a number is negative, I simply add 2^16. Solved in a stupid way, but solved nevertheless, albeit only for my specific problem.

Comment: @Nino The problem with `integer(kind=x)` is that it is not portable - but you probably know that already. It just happens kind=2 integers work as you want in your specific system but most probably won't work the same way in other. However, it is ok as a solution, as long you are aware of the lack of portability and it works for you as it is.

Comment: @Pap I do not know what is and what is not portable, to be honest. But, from the discussion between clearly knowledgeable and sophisticated fortran experts like yourself and Vladimir I'm learning a lot. I feel like a student of fencing, admiring your interplay and happy that I can admire it from a distance. The more verbose the better, from where I sit.  So, thank you. FYI, I didn't know I had to activate the check mark to give you guys credit when it is due: I did this now.

Comment: @Pap I compiled your program on my system: it does work, thank you. But, I do not see how you can get away with not specifying the byte length of the integers msb and lsb, or the character ch for that matter. I had to experiment a little before I found out that integer(kind=2) and character(len=2) works differenty, and better, than the default integer(kind=4). And, which of the various declarations (integer*2 as I've used earlier, and now (kind=4) is preferred? (the most explicit, portable, whatever)?

Comment: @Nino Any `kind=<number>` is not preferred because it's not portable. For example, `kind=4` is not guaranteed to mean the same thing on any compiler.. This is why Fortran introduced `selected_int_kind`, but even that won't work in your case. And even if you declare your integers as `kind=c_int16_t` or `int16` (both are portable), you will still need to read the TIFF content byte-by-byte, due to the way TIFF data are stored in the binary file. So why bother doing that, given the solution I posted works with bytes as well, doesn't have portability issues, and works on any compiler, old or new.

Comment: One reason I'd want to keep reading the data into 16-bit integers is that I want to write out what I computed from the data to the same .tif file, in the same way, so that the same program I use to look at the data (ImageJ) can also look at what I computed. By reading the bytes one by one I'd have to restructure the 15-bit plus sign bit number, in a way I'm not yet comfortable with. I sidestep that by making sure that the number I write are all below 32767, hence don't need the sign bit that would otherwise contribute 32768 to the number.

Answer (score 1):

Your `read` statement will simply read 2 characters for `tifhead(1)`, the next 2 characters for `tifhead(2)`, etc, *including spaces*. Therefore you end up with `tifhead(1)="49"`, `tifhead(2)=" 4"`, `tifhead(3)="9 "`, and so on. You think you read the first 2 bytes correctly only because you print the strings "49", " 4", "9 ",... one after the other, so it looks like "49 49 " in the output. The compiler has no way to know there is a single blank space separating strings and 2 spaces every four data.

To read your data properly you must use formatted `read`ing which implies you must also declare your `stream` as 'formatted' in the `open` statement. The following example shows how this can be done:

```
program example
implicit none
character(len=2) :: tifhead(8), greyscale(8)
open(1, file="example.txt", access='stream', form='formatted')
read(1, "(4(a2,tr1),tr1,3(a2,tr1),a2)", advance='no') tifhead
read(1, "(tr2,4(a2,tr1),tr1,3(a2,tr1),a2)", advance='no') greyscale
close(1)
print "(a,7(a2,tr1),a2,a)", "  tifhead = (", tifhead, ")"
print "(a,7(a2,tr1),a2,a)", "greyscale = (", greyscale, ")"
end program example
```

Perhaps some explanation is needed: `a2,tr1` means read a string of 2 characters, then advance the reading pointer once (this skips the space between your hexadecimal "numbers" - actually, they are treated as just strings). `4(a2,tr1)` means do that 4 times. This reads the first 4 bytes plus one space. Now, there is one more space before the next data to be read so we add `tr1` to skip it, and our format is `4(a2,tr1),tr1` so far; then we read 3 more bytes with `3(a2,tr1)`, then the last byte alone with just `a2` (not skipping the space after it). So the format string is `(4(a2,tr1),tr1,3(a2,tr1),a2)`, which will read the first 8 bytes correctly, leaving the reading pointer right after the 8th byte. Note that `advance='no'` is necessary, otherwise Fortran will assume carriage return and will skip the rest of the data in the same record (line).

Now, to read the next 8 bytes we use the same format, except we add `tr2` in the beginning to skip the two blank spaces. I added formatted printing in the program to check if data were read correctly. Running the program gives:

```
  tifhead = (49 49 2A 00 08 00 20 00)
greyscale = (00 00 0B 02 00 00 00 00)
```

which verifies data were read correctly.

Last but not least, I would recommend to avoid old-fashion Fortran used in your code and the example above. This means use `newunit` to let the program find the first free unit instead of explicitly giving a unit number, have some way to check if the file you are trying to open actually exists or if you reached end of file, avoid unnamed arguments, use the `dimension` attribute to declare arrays, etc. None of those is strictly necessary, and it might look like unnecessary verbosity at first. But in the long run being strict (as modern Fortran encourages) will save you a lot of time while debugging larger programs. So the above example could (arguably should) be written as follows.

```
program example2
implicit none
integer :: unt, status
character(len=2), dimension(8) :: tifhead, greyscale
open(newunit=unt, file="example.txt", access='stream', form='formatted',&
     action='read', status='old', iostat=status)
if (status /= 0) then
  print "(a)","Error reading file."; stop
end if
! More sophisticated reading is probably needed to check for end of file.
read(unit=unt, fmt="(4(a2,tr1),tr1,3(a2,tr1),a2)", advance='no') tifhead
read(unit=unt, fmt="(tr2,4(a2,tr1),tr1,3(a2,tr1),a2)") greyscale
close(unit=unt)
print "(a,7(a2,tr1),a2,a)", "  tifhead = (", tifhead, ")"
print "(a,7(a2,tr1),a2,a)", "greyscale = (", greyscale, ")"
end program example2
```

Comment: I suspect we are interpreting the question rather differently.  It looks like you are assuming the file has _plain text_ like `49 49 2A 00  08 00 20 00` whereas I read it as being _binary_ which has the plain text representation when viewed by a hexfile viewer.  So, an unformatted stream connection is exactly what the user wants.

Comment: @francescalus: It could be as you said, I can't tell since not enough information is given. The question mentions hexedit, but then treats the data as strings, so I assumed data were exported to plain text. In fact, I suspected the data could actually be taken from a `tiff` image and, if that's true, I would provide a totally different answer. But I am only guessing.here. Maybe I should take the time needed to answer questions only when the question itself provides enough information.

Comment: Pap, it's indeed a .tif file, representing grey values from 0 to 65535. It's a 1024X1024 grid, so a million numbers. I might be able to read these byte by byte and then reconstruct the desired number in decimal, but there has to be a clever way. Hence my question to you all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data are actually stored in binary format (in fact it seems to be a `tiff` image data file), my first answer is valid only if you convert data to plain text. If you prefer to read the binary file directly, the simplest way I can think of is to open the file with `access='direct'`, and read data byte-by-byte. Each byte is read as a character, then it is converted to an integer, which I guess is more useful than a string supposed to represent a hexadecimal number.

As an example, the following program will read the header (first 8 bytes) from a `tiff` data file. The example reads data from a sample tiff image I found [here](https://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/sample/index.htm), but it works for any binary file.

```
program read_tiff_data
implicit none
integer :: unt, status, i
character :: ch
integer, dimension(8) :: tifhead

open(newunit=unt, file="flag_t24.tif", access='direct', form='unformatted',
     action='read', status='old', iostat=status, recl=1)
if (status /= 0) then
  print "(a)","Error reading file."; stop
end if
do i=1,8
  read(unit=unt, rec=i) ch; tifhead(i)=ichar(ch)
end do
close(unit=unt)

print "(a,7(i0,tr1),i0,a)", "tifhead = (", tifhead, ")"
end program read_tiff_data
```

The program gives this output:

```
tifhead = (73 73 42 0 8 0 0 0)
```

which is correct. You can easily expand the program to read more data from the file.

If you still need the hexadecimal representation, just replace `i0` with `z0` in the print statement so that it reads

```
print "(a,7(z0,tr1),z0,a)", "tifhead = (", tifhead, ")"
```

This will print the result in hexadecimals, in this case:

```
tifhead = (49 49 2A 0 8 0 0 0)
```

Comment: your response was very useful, it worked like a charm and taught me a lot of fortran syntax. But, after lots of experimenting, I haven't figured out how to generalize to the hexadecimals that I read: they represent 16-bit unsigned integers, from 0 to 65536: , namely

Comment: @Nino: I am not familiar with tiff binary format, but as far I know the header is 8-bit integers. If the rest of the data is indeed 16-bit, then the above example can be extended to read them. I will post such an example soon, must study the tiff file format first.

Comment: Pap, thank you for your help. FYI here is my solution. I don't know how to post a piece of code in a comment, so if this doesn't work I'll do it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works for me. Most of this is comments. Any remarks you may have on the fortran style are most welcome. Please note that I've been familiar with fortran 77 in the past, and learned a little more modern fortran in the process of writing this piece of code

```
  program putiff

c This program is solely intended to read the data from the .tif files made by the CCD camera
c PIXIS 1024F at beamline 1-BM at the Advanced Photon Source, so that they can be manipulated
c in fortran. It is not a general .tif reader.
c A little bit extra work may make this a reader for baseline .tif files,: some of the 
c information below may help with such an implementation.
c  
c The PIXIS .tif file is written in hex with the little-endian convention. 
c The hex numbers have two 8-bit bytes. They are read with an integer(kind=2) declaration.
c When describing an unsigned integer these cover numbers from 0 to 65535 (or 2**16-1). 
c For the PIXIS files the first two bytes are the decimal number 18761. The TIFF6 specification 
c gives them as a hexadecimal number (0x4949 for a little-endian convention, 4D4D for the
c big-endian convention. The PIXIS files are little-endian. 
c
c The next two bytes should be 42 decimal, and 0x2A.
c
c The next 4 bytes give the byte offset for the first image file directory (IFD) that contains
c all the other information needed to understand how the .tif files are put together.
c This number should be read together as a 4 byte integer (kind=4). These (unsigned) integers
c go from 0 to 2**32-1, or 4294967295: this is the maximum file length for a .tif file. 
c For the PIXIS this number is 2097160, or 0x200008: in between are the image date for the
c PIXIS's 1024x1024 pixels, each with a two-byte gray range from 0 to 2**16-1 (or 65535 decimal).   
c Therefore the PIXIS image can be read without understanding the IFD. 
c
c The line right below the hex representation gives the byte order, for the 
c little-endian convention indicated by two first bytes. It's 4949  for little-endian,
c in both the first and in the second byte separately. The byte order is then least importan
c part first; with two bytes together, it is byte by byte. For big-endian it is 4D4D.
c
c One way to confirm all this information is to look at the files
c with a binary editor (linux has xxd) or a binary editor (linux has hexedit).
c For the PIXIS image .tif file, the first 8 bytes in hexedit are indeed:
c   49 49    2A 00    08 00    20 00
c For a little-endian file, the bytes are read from the least important to the 
c most important within the two-byte number, like this:
c   49 49    2A 00    08 00    20 00
c  (34 12)  (34 12)  (78 56    34 12)
c Here the byte order is indicated below the numbers. The second two-byte number is
c therefore 2+2*16+0*256+0*4096, or 42. Likewise, the last 4-byte number is 0x00200008.  
c
c (When the individual byte are read in binary (with 'xxd -b -l 100') this gives   
c for the hexadecimals    49       49       2A       00       08       00       20       00
c         binary          01001001 01001001 00101010 00000000 00001000 00000000 00100000 00000000 
c         in ASCII        I        I        *        .        .        .        .        .        )

c After the PIXIS data comes the so-called IFD (Image File Directory).
c These contain 209 bytes. They mean something, but what I do not know. I printed them
c out one by one at the end of the program. Perhaps they are better read in two-byte units
c (right now they are read as 'integer(kind=1); integer(kind=2) may be better). But, then
c there's an odd number so you have to read one separately.

c I want to know these only because I want to use the same .tif format to
c write the results of rctopo (the max, the COM, the FWHM, and the spread).
c I know what's in the first 8 bytes, and what the data are, so I can just
c copy the ifd at the end and count on getting a good .tif file back. 
c It's sort of stupid, but it should work.
      use iso_fortran_env
      implicit logical (A-Z)
  
      integer                         :: j,jmin,jmax
      integer                         :: k,kmin,kmax
      integer                         :: ifdlength
      data jmin,kmin/1,1,/
      parameter(jmax=1024,kmax=1024)
      parameter(ifdlength=209)

c 8-byte header that starts the PIXIS data file
      integer (kind=2)                :: tifh12,tifh34 ! each two (8-bit) bytes
      integer (kind=4)                :: tifh5678      ! 4 bytes


c open and read the file now that you have the correct file name in the sequence
      open(newunit=unt,file='tiff_file,access='stream',iostat=ios)
      if (ios /= 0) then ; call problem(ios,'read_in_samples'); end if   
      read (unt) tifh12,tifh34,tifh5678,greyread,ifd
      close (unt)

      stop
      end
```

Comment: If you do `use iso_fortran_env` it is really good to use `integer(kind=int16)` instead of `integer (kind=2) ` and `integer(kind=int16)` instead of `integer (kind=2) ` for portability reasons. But it will work your way for most compilers in practice.