# What shall be used in recl when opening a file in unformatted direct access?

Tags: fortran, fortran95, flang

I am trying to fully understand how to deal with binary files in Fortran. Specifically, I am reading this [https://atmos.washington.edu/~salathe/osx_unix/endian.html](https://atmos.washington.edu/%7Esalathe/osx_unix/endian.html) which covers how to write binary files when the records to be written are fixed-length. This case is intended to allow a raw format that can be easily read/writen from/to other programming languages given that the endianess of the systems are the same (which is in the case in 2021, as as far as I know most practical systems are Little Endian now).

In the article, it is said to open the file using `direct` and `unformatted`.

```
open (unit=1, file='out.r4', form='unformatted', access='direct', recl=m*n*sizeofreal)
```

If I understood correctly how it works, the `recl` parameter is used to control the size of the records intended to be written.

**I have several doubts about how `recl` shall be used in Fortran:**

- Is it the size of the record in bytes?
- Does it depend on the compiler?
- Does it depend on the Fortran Standard we are using?
- If so, what are the differences among standards?
- Does the meaning of `recl` depend if we are writing derived types or "regular" types?

My experimentation suggest that using the `bytes` size of the derived type when writing derived type records is adequate; but I do not know if that is dependant on the specific compiler I am using or not.

By default I am trying to do things using `flang` and Fortran 95 (just to learn a standard which is fully compatible with `f2py`).

Comment: Take a look at [Reading writing fortran direct access unformatted files with different compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686720/reading-writing-fortran-direct-access-unformatted-files-with-different-compilers). I am very tempted to suggest this as a duplicate - my only concern is that off the top of my head I am not sure when inquire by output list came into the language, either Fortran 90 or Fortran 2003.

Comment: So if I understood that post correctly, no standard dictates what `recl` shall be (bytes or block size) and it is compiler/system dependent. But, you can inquire `iolength` to get the actual IO recl size in your system. You just do not know which standard that belongs. From the linked post: "The other alternative is to not worry about the option and use the inquire intrinsic to query the iolength for your array. "

Comment: Correct. Pad ... pad ...

Comment: Would the `iolength` inquire return the `recl` block size in bytes?

Comment: And I'm going to say it again, I would strongly encourage you to move to at least Fortran 2003 - there are at least two free, good quality compilers out there, hamstringing yourself by sticking to what is now a very old version does seem strange to me.

Comment: No. In the appropriate units for the compiler to use in a RECL= for an open of a direct access file

Comment: I am not fully sure that you can freely use Fortran 2003 with `f2py`, which is part of my agenda. Even if I move to Fortran 2003, I like to understand the standards (same for C, I try to clearly understand different standard changes).

Comment: I think that the poster might wish to consider stream access instead of direct.  I suspect that the webpage that is cited may have been written before stream existed.   Steam will achieve the compiler/language portability goals, without needing the record length information.  If you want fixed length records, just write fixed length records.

Comment: Absolutely, firect access wss often used as poor-man's stream access before F2003.

Comment: I do not know if that is applicable in Fortran but in C++ and for my particular environment using streams was slower. In my case I have to deal with fixed-width records. For reading I check the size of the file and I read the whole array at once, which is very useful for my particular use case.