# Problems Reading Direct Access Binary File in Fortran

Tags: binary, fortran

I have been testing reading and writing in binary on Fortran, but have come across issues.

Here is the code for writing the array into the file called 'out.r4':

```
program write

    integer m,n, sizeofreal
    parameter (m=3, n=3, sizeofreal=4)
    real x(m,n)


    X(1,:)=(/0.111111, 0.22222222, 0.3333333/)
    X(2,:)= (/ 0.444444, 0.5555555, 0.6666666/)
    X(3,:)= (/ 0.777777, 0.8888888, 0.9999999/)


    open (unit=1,file='out.r4',form='unformatted',access='direct',recl=m*n*sizeofreal)


    write (1,rec=1) x

end
```

The file 'out.r4' looks something like: *Žã=*Žã>e G?9Žc>ã8 ?7Žc?ªªª>ªª*?þÿ ?

I assume this is how the binary should appear if opened with a text editor.

Now here is the read code:

```
program read

    integer m,n
    parameter (m=3, n=3)
    real x(m,n)


    open (unit=1, file='out.r4',form='unformatted', access='direct',recl=m*4)


      do j = 1, n
        read (1,rec=j) (x(i,j), i=1,m)
      end do
      
      do j = 1, n
        write (*,*) (x(i,j), i=1,m)
      end do

end
```

The output appears in a 3x3 array like expected, but the numbers are different:

```
-285.516  -42.560   0.03198
0.077777  5.266e21  7.808e-5
-45.8115  -47.8472  -85.3802
```

Can anyone help me to get the correct output when reading the binary file?

Comment: You write one record to the file, but then try to read from three records?  Do you have an older version of the file with three records of junk? (Try `status='replace'` in your writing open.)

Comment: Welcome, please take the Welcome [tour]. Please always make sure you always format the code and other data in your posts properly, see the edits I made.

Comment: Be aware that using `sizeofreal=4` is incorrect. Some compilers measure their records in bytes, other in words. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686720/reading-writing-fortran-direct-access-unformatted-files-with-different-compilers You must use `inquire` to get the `recl`.

Comment: As another aside, generally avoid using unit numbers below 10 when opening files. Compilers tend to allocate stdin/stdout/stderr somewhere in that range.